# JUnit - Manipulate Output File

Tags: java, testing, junit, io, testcase

The output of my JUnit test cases has `Request Content` and `Response Content` with it.

I've been using default std output file through:

> Run Configurations > Common > Output file

and this prints the console output from there.

How can I split the file - one containing the `Request Content` (and save the file as REQUEST) and the other is `Response Content` (save as RESPONSE file) ?

Also, I have multiple test cases from one JUNit class. How can I set 1 Request output file and 1 Response output file per test case being ran?

TIA!

Comment: Code references are highly recommended to understand better what you are trying to do. Could you provide some?